# How to write code that returns a boolean value upon completing JSON Schema Validation

Tags: java, json

I need help with writing code to do a JSON Schema validation. I've already written code that does the schema validation, but unfortunately, I cannot return a boolean value because the method returns void.

I don't know of any other library that would help with this.

Library:

```
org.json.JSONObject;
org.everit.json.schema.Schema;
org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader
```

This is my current code:

```
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(response);

        JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(
                new JSONTokener(JSONSchemaValidation.class.getResourceAsStream("/biographics_schema.schema.json")));
        JSONObject jsonSubject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener((reader)));

        Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchema);
        schema.validate(jsonSubject);
```

As you can see, there's no way of checking if schema validation was valid or false.

Can someone help me write code that checks to see if schema validation was successful?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with invalid json? Would expect an exception, in which case trap ot and return false.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, yep I tried it with an invalid JSON. Upon running the code, in the console it details an exception was thrown and what caused that. But I cannot even use try and catch

Comment: Why can't you use try catch????

Answer (score 0):

From the latest [API](http://erosb.github.io/everit-json-schema/javadoc/1.9.2/org/everit/json/schema/Schema.html#validate-java.lang.Object-) available from the `org.everit.json` GitHub [project](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema#javadoc), an invocation of `Schema#validate` will throw [ValidationException](http://erosb.github.io/everit-json-schema/javadoc/1.9.2/org/everit/json/schema/ValidationException.html) if your schema is invalid. 
You may want to `try`/`catch` and return `false` in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception that `validate()` throws:

```
try {
    schema.validate(jsonSubject);
    return true;
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [javadoc](http://erosb.github.io/everit-json-schema/javadoc/1.9.2/org/everit/json/schema/Schema.html#validate-java.lang.Object-):

> public void validate(Object subject) Performs the schema validation.
>   Parameters: subject - the object to be validated Throws:
>   ValidationException - if the subject is invalid against this schema.

So if you want to check wehter it was successful you need to catch the exception. Since `ValidationEception` extends RuntimeException it is an unchecked exception, this means you are not forced to do a try-catch block.

So what you can do is following:

```
boolean valid;
try{
 schema.validate(jsonSubject);
 valid = true;
} catch (ValidationException e){
 valid = false;
}
```